# -(id)init method-app crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have used Crashlytics to catch errors in my application. Sometimes app is crashing and Crashlytics says  that the error is in following code block.I have declared all variables in .h file.

```
-(id)init
{
    if ( self = [super init] ) {
    _currentTemperature=@"";
    _currentHumidity=@"";
    _currentWindSpeed=@"";
    _currentStatus=@"";
    self.weeklyMinTemperature=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.weeklyMaxTemperature=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.weeklyHumidity=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.hourlySummary=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    }
    return self;
}
```

The error log is like following.

EXC_BAD_ACCESS_KERN_INVALID ADDRESS

```
#6. Crashed: com.apple.UNSNotificationSchedulerConnection
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x182ae1b90 objc_msgSend + 16
1  Foundation                     0x183d517a8 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 484
2  UIKit                          0x188c8b1ec -[UIConcreteLocalNotification encodeWithCoder:] + 84
3  Foundation                     0x183d51870 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 684
4  Foundation                     0x183dbad48 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 264
5  Foundation                     0x183d51870 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 684
6  Foundation                     0x183d51d58 encodeInvocationArguments + 320
7  Foundation                     0x183d51a18 -[NSXPCEncoder encodeInvocation:] + 368
8  Foundation                     0x183d51870 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 684
9  Foundation                     0x183f27d64 -[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:withProxy:remoteInterface:withErrorHandler:timeout:userInfo:] + 2328
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18346ea1c ___forwarding___ + 408
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18336cc5c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb54bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec14c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec3914 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd020 start_wqthread + 4

--

#0. com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182febea8 read + 8
1  Foundation                     0x183d73f0c _NSReadFromFileDescriptorWithProgress + 228
2  Foundation                     0x183d73cec _NSReadBytesFromFileWithExtendedAttributes + 676
3  Foundation                     0x183d739f8 -[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfFile:] + 80
4  GeoServices                    0x189e8ec2c -[GEOResourceManifestManager _loadActiveTileGroupIfNecessary:] + 240
5  GeoServices                    0x189d2f3e8 GEOURLWorldDefaultURLStringWithSource + 164
6  GeoServices                    0x189d43658 _GEOURLStringWithSource + 56
7  GeoServices                    0x189e0d824 +[GEOLocationShifter isLocationShiftRequiredForCoordinate:] + 72
8  GeoServices                    0x189e7c970 -[_GEOReverseGeocodeRequestTicket submitWithHandler:networkActivity:] + 168
9  CoreLocation                   0x18a1f3eb4 (null) + 32576
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb54bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ebab84 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
13 CoreFoundation                 0x183420d50 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
14 CoreFoundation                 0x18341ebb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628
15 CoreFoundation                 0x183348c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
16 GraphicsServices               0x184c30088 GSEventRunModal + 180
17 UIKit                          0x188632088 UIApplicationMain + 204
18 AgileblazeWeather              0x100053b78 main (main.m:14)
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ee68b8 (Missing)

#1. com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1830054d8 kevent_qos + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec87d8 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb7648 _dispatch_source_invoke + 50

#2. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x183004b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd020 start_wqthread + 4

#3. com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x1446aa130.events
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fe902c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec6394 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 160
2  CoreLocation                   0x18a1bad4c (null) + 628
3  CoreLocation                   0x18a1bf804 (null) + 1176
4  CoreLocation                   0x18a1fac44 (null) + 60624
5  CoreLocation                   0x18a1f8898 (null) + 51492
6  CoreLocation                   0x18a1f87cc (null) + 51288
7  CoreLocation                   0x18a1f9a18 (null) + 55972
8  libxpc.dylib                   0x183100f68 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
9  libxpc.dylib                   0x1830fed10 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 2132
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb5578 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb9864 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 656
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec1694 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1332
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb8978 _dispatch_mach_invoke + 600
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec1694 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1332
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec1694 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1332
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec3914 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd020 start_wqthread + 4

#4. com.apple.NSXPCConnection.m-user.com.apple.usernotification.notificationscheduler
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fe8fd8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fe8e54 mach_msg + 72
2  libxpc.dylib                   0x18311314c xpc_pipe_routine + 256
3  libxpc.dylib                   0x183105f18 _xpc_interface_routine + 200
4  libxpc.dylib                   0x1831062f0 _xpc_look_up_endpoint + 224
5  libxpc.dylib                   0x1830ffc60 _xpc_connection_bootstrap_look_up_slow + 212
6  libxpc.dylib                   0x1830ff958 _xpc_connection_init + 536
7  libxpc.dylib                   0x1830ff730 _xpc_connection_resume_init + 20
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec14c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec3914 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd020 start_wqthread + 4

#5. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x183004b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd020 start_wqthread + 4

#6. Crashed: com.apple.UNSNotificationSchedulerConnection
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x182ae1b90 objc_msgSend + 16
1  Foundation                     0x183d517a8 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 484
2  UIKit                          0x188c8b1ec -[UIConcreteLocalNotification encodeWithCoder:] + 84
3  Foundation                     0x183d51870 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 684
4  Foundation                     0x183dbad48 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 264
5  Foundation                     0x183d51870 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 684
6  Foundation                     0x183d51d58 encodeInvocationArguments + 320
7  Foundation                     0x183d51a18 -[NSXPCEncoder encodeInvocation:] + 368
8  Foundation                     0x183d51870 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 684
9  Foundation                     0x183f27d64 -[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:withProxy:remoteInterface:withErrorHandler:timeout:userInfo:] + 2328
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18346ea1c ___forwarding___ + 408
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18336cc5c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb54bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec14c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x182eb547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec3914 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ec30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd020 start_wqthread + 4

#7. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  AgileblazeWeather              0x10006c74c CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4295460684
1  AgileblazeWeather              0x10006c74c CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4295460684
2  AgileblazeWeather              0x10006cb6c CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4295461740
3  AgileblazeWeather              0x10005d82c CLSHandler + 4295399468
4  AgileblazeWeather              0x1000589b0 CLSMachExceptionServer + 4295379376
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cfb28 _pthread_body + 156
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cfa8c _pthread_body + 154
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd028 thread_start + 4

#8. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fe8fd8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fe8e54 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x183420c60 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18341e964 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4  CoreFoundation                 0x183348c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5  CFNetwork                      0x183ac9bcc +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
6  Foundation                     0x183e3fe4c __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cfb28 _pthread_body + 156
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cfa8c _pthread_body + 154
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd028 thread_start + 4

#9. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x183004b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd020 start_wqthread + 4

#10. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x183004b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd020 start_wqthread + 4

#11. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x183004b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd020 start_wqthread + 4

#12. com.apple.CFSocket.private
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x183004344 __select + 8
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1834271c8 __CFSocketManager + 648
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cfb28 _pthread_body + 156
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cfa8c _pthread_body + 154
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830cd028 thread_start + 4
```

What is the reason for this type of crash?Is there any mistake in my code block?

Comment: Show the crash log.

Comment: #0
Crashed: com.apple.UNSNotificationSchedulerConnection
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x000000001445b968
 Raw Text
0 libobjc.A.dylib 
objc_msgSend + 16
1 Foundation 
-[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 484
2
UIKit 
-[UIConcreteLocalNotification encodeWithCoder:] + 84
20
libsystem_pthread.dylib 
start_wqthread + 4
(Missing)

Comment: Yeah update your question so we can read it.

Comment: I have searched in SO and found that this type of error is due to memory management issue.But i cant find where the memory leaks.any problem in my code block?

Comment: No, it's fine.  It's more likely an issue with the allocation of *that* object itself, and therefore we need to see the stack trace.

Comment: I have edited my question and updated the crash log.Please go through it.

Comment: The stacks have a lot of XPC stuff scattered through them, which seems to be related to local notifications.  Does the object that you're creating have something to do with notifications?

Comment: Yes,The  weeklyMinTemperature array and weeklyMaxTemperature array stores next 48 hours minimum temperature and maximum temperature respectively of the current location.This array values will stored in a local db and schedule the values for local motification.ie,User will get the minimum and maximum temperature of the current location as notification in each hours.

Comment: Have you figured out the issue? I am also facing similar crashes in my application. I am also using local notification. @PhillipMills  any help is appreciated.